# Perform Crossover between two 2D arrays (JAVA)

Tags: java, logic, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to make a genetic algorithm for optimizing a seating problem where people have preferences of who they want to sit next to. The problem I'm having is with the crossover stage. I have two members of a population that I want to breed and produce a child member. Typically, one would take a 'gene' from one parent and a different gene from another. The issue is placement matters in the context of seating at a table.

Here is a randomly generated example:

```
i   j   Child Value  Mother Value    Father Value
0   0                  P08             P00
0   1                  P11             P06
0   2                  P02             P05
0   3                  P12             P09  
0   4                  P07             P04
1   0                  P09             P10  
1   1                  P01             P01
1   2                  P03             P13  
1   3                  P06             P03  
1   4                  P13             P11  
2   0                  P00             P12  
2   1                  P10             P07  
2   2                  P04             P02  
2   3                  P05             P08      
2   4                  P14             P14
```

I want to generate a child that has characteristics of both parents but also has no duplicate objects (PXX shouldn't occur twice in the child).

i : Represents the Table number. Here there are 3 tables 
j : Represents the seat number. Here there are 5 Seats
Total of 15 people.

Any good way to do this and sorry if my explanation is confusing. 
Note I can't use any genetic algorithm libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of problem the solution is often to "repair" the child. You need a repairing function which will take an infeasible child (one with duplicates) and make it feasible (remove the duplicates and replace them by the missing values).

For your particular case, another way of fixing this issue would be to take all non-overlapping tables from the parents and put them in the child, and fill the missing tables of the child with the remainder of the people (e.g., in your example take table 1 from Mother and table 2 from Father–they have no people in common–and put the rest of the people in table 0).